# Three.js Blender Animation Mic Frequency Trigger Issue

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender, getusermedia

I am attempting to import a multiple layer animation from Blender exported using the three.js plugin into JavaScript and have the different animations triggered by microphone frequency input. I have been able to combine the playing of the animations via buttons and a .obj being rotated depending on the frequency from mic input. But I am struggling to assign the mic to the animation.

```
<div class="info">
      <button onclick="fadeAction( 'idle' );">idle</button>
      <button onclick="fadeAction( 'run' );">run</button>
      <button onclick="fadeAction( 'wrap' );">wrap</button>
    </div>

    loader.load( 'tentacleanimation6.json', function( geometry, materials ) {
        materials.forEach( function ( material ) {
        material.skinning = true;
            } );

        mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(
        geometry,
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials )
        );

        mixer  = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
        action.idle  = mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 1 ] );
        action.run   = mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 0 ] );
        action.wrap   = mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 2 ] );
        action.idle.setEffectiveWeight( 1 );
        action.run.setEffectiveWeight( 1 );
        action.wrap.setEffectiveWeight( 1 );

        action.idle.play();

        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.x = -3;
        scene.add( mesh );
        } );

        fadeAction = function () {
        var activeActionName = 'idle';
        return function ( name ) {
        var from = action[ activeActionName ].play();
        var to   = action[ name ].play();
        from.enabled = true;
        to.enabled = true;
        from.crossFadeTo( to, .3 );
        activeActionName = name;
            }
                }();
```

Then the mic input from getUserMedia is processed as followed triggering a .obj file to rotate:

```
script_processor_analysis_node.onaudioprocess = function() {
   analyser_node.getByteFrequencyData(array_freq_domain);
   if (microphone_stream.playbackState == microphone_stream.PLAYING_STATE) {    
       var render = function () {
       for ( var i = 0; i < (array_freq_domain.length); i++ ){
       var valueone = array_freq_domain[array_freq_domain.length / 2];
       mouthone.rotation.x = deg2rad( valueone ) / 7;
       var valuetwo = array_freq_domain[6];
       mouthtwo.rotation.x = deg2rad( valuetwo ) / 7;
                }
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
           }
       requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
       }
```

The issue becomes when the two are combined and I am not sure what needs to be called in the onaudioprocess section to trigger an animation to play? Also there seems to be an issue with rendering, as the function for onaudioprocess needs to be rendered as above and the animation needs to be rendered with the following and when these are combined they cancel each other out:

```
;( function update () {
  requestAnimationFrame( update );
  var delta = clock.getDelta();
  var theta = clock.getElapsedTime();
  if ( mixer ) { mixer.update( delta ); }
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
        } )();
```

Comment: Sounds like [old Chrome-only stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Porting_webkitAudioContext_code_to_standards_based_AudioContext#Removal_of_AudioBufferSourceNode.playbackState_and_OscillatorNode.playbackState).